# Renting a manual transmission motorbike in Ubud

Tags: rental, indonesia

I'd like to rent a motorbike in Ubud, Indonesia.  EVERYBODY has automatics available for rent, but nobody seems to be renting manuals ):

I suppose I could use an automatic if I absolutely had to, but I really prefer manual.

Is there a place in Ubud that rents manual transmission motorbikes?  How much does it cost?

Comment: In the meantime, I went ahead and rented an automatic scooter for a couple of days. Wow these things handle WAAAAAAY differently than motorcycles!

So far, I've managed to brake REALLY hard attempting to pull in the "clutch", and I've stomped on the floor a few times trying to activate the rear brake :P

Answer (score 2):

[PT Amerthadana Car Rental](http://www.amerthadana.com/?vehicletype=motorcycle&manufacturer=&transmission=manual-transmission&pricerange=11-20&capacity=2) appears to. The link I've provided does a sample manual search for motorcylces, and as at the time I'm writing this, it's showing Kawasakis, Hondas, and Yahamas in manual transmission.

While their Main Office is located in Blumbungan, Sibang Kaja, Badung Regency on Java, they have a Branch office at Warkudara Street. No. 104, Kuta,Bali – Indonesia.

Comment: Kuta is not really in Ubud, so beware of the traffic. While google maps claims that Kuta is only 45 minutes away, it can take you 1-2 hours to get there. Still, this company might be your only chance to get one with manual transmission.

Comment: @uncovery you're right, google map is very optimistic, seems to be very often the case for Indonesian routes it estimates ^^ I did that ride by scooter, on a Monday (early afternoon), it took around 1h.